# BannerSlider Extension

Tags: php, magento

I'm using the [BannerSlider Extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/banner-slider-3912.html) and it works great but for design purposes I need it to include it in a template.

At this moment I'm using it with the CMS like this:

```
{{block type='bannerslider/bannerslider' template='bannerslider/bannerslider.phtml'}}
```

How can I get the PHP code for that single line, to add it directly to my template ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create cms/block and place your code

```
{{block type='bannerslider/bannerslider' template='bannerslider/bannerslider.phtml'}}
```

and then you can call anywhere in template that cms/block like this

```
<?php 
     echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('YOUR IDENTIFIER')->toHtml() 
?>
```